# Button click not triggering in popover form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-click-event

I have a cancel button that should get triggered to close my popover. But the click event doesn't get triggered. Can anyone see what is wrong here, might be something stupid because I'm a newbie!

Do I need to add something before '#cancelEvent'? ex. someparentelement#cancelEvent

The line above the cancel button submits the form, so that works, the cancel button just doesn't work..

```js
var $calPopOver;


$(document).ready(function (of) {
    $("#overview").hide();
    $("#details").hide();
    $("#listing").hide();
    $("#address").hide();
    $("#map").hide();
    $("#images").hide();
    $("#eventcalendar").show();
    

    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next', //today',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        //eventLimit: 1,
        //eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
        //views: {
        //    agenda: {
        //        eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
        //    }
        //},
        events: '/ManageSpaces/GetDiaryEvents/',

        //eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
            
        //},
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //function (data, event, view) {
            //var s = cellInfo.segs;
            $("#eventDetails.collapse").collapse('toggle');

            if ($calPopOver)
                $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
        },
        dayClick: function (data, event, view) {
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-content").html();
                }
            });
            
            //$(this).popover('toggle');
            if ($calPopOver) {
                $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
            }
            $calPopOver = $(this).popover('show');
        }
    });
  });

$("#cancelEvent").click(function () {
    $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
});
```

```html
<div id="eventcalendar">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div id='fullcalendar' style="width:100%"></div>
                <div id="day-popover-head" class="hide">Add Event</div>
                <div id="day-popover-content" class="hide">
                    @*<form role="form">*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="timeSelect">Select time:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="timeSelect">
                                
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <label for="timeDuration">Select duration:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="timeDuration">
                                <option value="30">30 min</option>
                                <option value="45">45 min</option>
                                <option value="60">60 min</option>
                                <option value="75">75 min</option>
                                <option value="90">90 min</option>
                                <option value="105">105 min</option>
                                <option value="120">120 min</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" id="cancelEvent" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    @*</form>*@
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="eventDetails" class="col-md-2 collapse" style="background-color:yellow;">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Will you please post all of the relevant JavaScript?  E.g. we would need to see where $calPopOver is created in the first place, and how the click event binding fits into the bigger picture.

Comment: just added relevant js

Comment: Could you add the rest of the HTML?  E.g. There is no #fullcalendar in the source you posted, so it's hard to reproduce without guessing.

Comment: added more html as requested. Tried removing the form around the button, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way the click event is bound and you should be in business:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEvent', function () {
    alert('Doing cancel...');
    $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/m6kpjj5g/

Comment: how is this different then just calling .click()? The reason I ask is because I have other click events in this .js file that are constructed with just the id then .click and they seem to work.

Comment: Without looking at the source of the calendar plugin, I would guess that the plugin is cloning the HTML you give it in "day-popover-content", which means that the cancel button you click within the popover in the calendar isn't the same one you bound to on document.ready. To get around that, bind to the document click event and give it a filter to use when deciding whether or not to handle the event. That's a common solution when you're dealing with dynamic elements.